# How could I handle rude and offensive comments kindly?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, rude-or-abusive

I was recently editing and browsing questions, and stopped by in a specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218800/jmeter-validate-response-headers-and-their-values?noredirect=1#45220159) (**Edit:** now question was removed by user) to post a guidance message containing useful links and tips. This was my comment:

> Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

For this, the user later answered with a rude and offensive response, regarding the supposed lack of usefulness my comment was. I replied kindly explaining my reasons for posting that guidance comment, and the user replied again with a rude and offensive response.

I decided to flag those comments as rude (they are removed now as well as my kind response), but besides that I wonder if I should have handled the situation differently? Should I have refrained from answering to his first comment and just flag his? Should I continue to reply him kindly to urge him a better attitude?

**Edit:** I do not usually feel comfortable with just "shrug and skip", as I believe that in those situations we should at least try to reason with that person; maybe they just are having a bad day and some kind words could make someone assume a better attitude.

Comment: Just shrug and skip.

Comment: F*** them. Trying to get people to behave like decent human beings by being nice rarely works. Ignore and walk away.

Comment: That said, there is something to be said for customizing comments a bit so they don't look like a standard message you post everywhere. That's never an excuse for rudeness, but I can see how to someone in a bad mood/feeling intimidated by the place/being under a lot of stress a comment like that could come across as condescending. One could try to point out something that's wrong with the specific post.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes you are right, I actually reformatted my usual response to sound more friendly, and I most of the times also add more to the comment if something specific can be pointed out.

Comment: Sometimes it's not necessarily even a lack of friendliness; more the feeling that the commenter actually read the individual question in detail. But as said, none of this justifies a rude and offensive response, ever.

Comment: _we should at least try to reason with that person_ By all means do that if you can organise it, just don't do it in the comments of a question/answer. Thats not what comments are meant to be used for. If you've made your point, and you're happy it's a valid one, phrased respectfully, you've done everything you should.

Comment: Attempting to moderate someone's comments without having moderator powers is a bad idea. You can't make someone behave decently. In any case, removing yourself as a target to abuse is the easiest way to make them stop acting like a jerk. (And any attempts to talk them down are just noise anyway, as Clive just said.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 you have an interesting idea about auto-comments and tailoring. FYI: I have slightly rephrased your comment and raised an issue [here](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/room-meeting-topics/issues/10) for the next SOCVR room meeting to have it discussed.

Comment: @rene The approach I will be taking now is to have a base comment I can copy/paste that has a section where I can add a personal or custom comment about the problem of the Asker, to make it sound more supportive and empathic, and also less condescending (and not sound like "Mr.Cop" as that user said to me)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Should I have refrained from answering to his first comment and just flag his?

Yes.

> Should I continue to reply him kindly to urge him a better attitude?

No.